# Sql developer after turn on is giving WARNING:

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle10g

I have installed Oracle Database 10g Client (10.2.0.4) on my laptop. After I run Sqldeveloper is giving that warning:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jEGh.png)

Could you give me some hint what should I do ?
Thank you

Comment: Oracle 10g is rather old. Which SQL Developer version did you install? Is it compatible with 10g client?

Comment: I found that information on this forum:
"Oracle Database includes SQL Developer but SQL Developer doesn't include a database."
Sql developer came with Oracle Database 10g Client so I am asouming that Sql developer is complatible with it.

Comment: Umm ... no, that's hardly true. Oracle database is one software product. Client is another. SQL Developer is yet another, a GUI tool which is *installed* separately. It does require database (because, what would you connect it to?) which doesn't have to be installed on the same computer, but has to be accessible, somehow (usually over the network). Besides, every Oracle database version has its own client (e.g. Oracle 10g has 10g Client; 18c has 18c client, and so on). SQL Developer started as *Project Raptor" in 2005 or 2006 (unless I'm wrong) and had many versions since. Which one is yours?

Comment: for best support don't post pictures of errors, copy the error text directly into the question, otherwise there's no way for others to search and find what they're looking for

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your install of 10g Client.

Something is corrupted/bad with your SQL Developer install.

Things to try:

1. redownload 22.4.1, extract zip to a FRESH directory on your machine
2. if that doesn't work, find the system22.4.1.../system_cache folder in AppData, delete it

C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system22.2.0.173.2018\system_cache

Comment: Deleting the folder did it for me. No need for the fresh directory.

Comment: deleting it means you nuked all of your settings, sql history, connections etc - so you have nothing to recover your stuff - but yeah, that will also fix it